# How to receive ERC-20 payments with Web3.js?

Tags: web3js, tokens, erc-20, signature

My main goal is to get an erc-20 token from this user, but when sending it to the blockchain network, I need to have it signed by the user, but how can I get the user to sign it?

```
      //Send ERC-20 Tokens
      const userAccount = account;
      const amount = web3.utils.toHex(1e18);
      const toAddress = address;
      let count;

      // get transactin count, later will used as nonce
      web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account).then((v) => (count = v));

      const contractAddress = '0xed24fc36d5ee211ea25a80239fb8c4cfd80f12ee';
      const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress, {
        from: userAccount,
      });

      const rawTransaction = {
        from: userAccount,
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(2 * 1e18),
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
        to: contractAddress,
        value: '0x0',
        data: contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, amount).encodeABI(),
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(count),
      };

      const transcation = new Tx(rawTransaction);
      console.log(transaction);
      const signatures = web3.eth.personal.sign(transaction);

      web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'));

      // check the balance
      contract.methods
        .balanceOf(userAccount)
        .call()
        .then((balance) => console.log(balance));
```

Here's the situation where I'm stuck.

```
      const transcation = new Tx(rawTransaction);
      console.log(transaction);
      const signatures = web3.eth.personal.sign(transaction);

      web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'));
```

Comment: Do you have the private key? It seems you are already using '@ethereumjs/tx', in that case just follow the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/tree/master/packages/tx#legacy-transactions).

Comment: No, I don't have a secret key. I just want to get busd token from user. Can you suggest me an article or video for this?

Comment: If you don't have the address's private key nor the seed phrase then you can't access those funds.

Comment: So I guess I should have said that. I want to get busd token for my service from user. I did some research, but I decided to do it this way, right? How can I get paid can you give me an idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple guys :)

This way I was able to get paid and I don't need to get your user's signature.
Good Times :)

```js
async function paidBusd() {
    const tokenAddress = '0xed24fc36d5ee211ea25a80239fb8c4cfd80f12ee';
    const contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi, tokenAddress);
    const tokenBalance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(account).call();
    console.log(`BUSD balance: ${tokenBalance / 10 ** 18}`);
    const tokenCount = tokenBalance / 10 ** 18;

    if (chainId === 97 && tokenCount > 0) {
      const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
      const tokenTransferResult = await contract.methods.transfer(address, web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether')).send({
        from: account,
        gasPrice,
      });
      console.log(tokenTransferResult);
    }
  }
```